# Framework7: How to get page content-block-inner width and height (without navbar and toolbar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-framework-7

How to get page content-block-inner width and height (without navbar and toolbar), since it varies between devices and OSes.

I've tried giving id to content-block-inner then using `$$('#test').height;`,  but it failed.

```
<!-- Pages, because we need fixed-through navbar and toolbar, it has additional appropriate classes-->
<div class="pages navbar-through toolbar-through">
    <!-- Page, data-page contains page name-->
    <div data-page="index" class="page">
        <!-- Scrollable page content-->
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="content-block" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" id="test">
                <div class="content-block-inner" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                    <div id="mypage" style="width:100%; height:80vh; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="toolbar" style="width:100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" id="draw_toolbar">
                    <div class="toolbar-inner">
                        <i class="icon icon-bars" onclick="test()"></i>
                        <i class="icon icon-bars" onclick="test()"></i>
                        <i class="icon icon-bars" onclick="test()"></i>
                        <i class="icon icon-bars" onclick="test()"></i>
                        <i class="icon icon-bars" onclick="test()"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the return value of `$$('#test').height`;

```
function(){
    return this[0]===window?window.innerHeight:this.length>0>parseFloat
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `id="test"`, then the selector should be `$$('#test')`.

In your example above the hash (#) is not present.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add # in this question, i've edited it.
i did use it, but it return  this :

the return value of $$('#test').height;
'function(  {returnthis[0]===window?window.innerHeight:this.length>0>parseFloat'